# Monitoring the Training Progress through PutAppend

Tags: list-manipulation, export, neural-networks

I would like to export the round loss during my model training for each training round. Currently, I am using the way shown in the Documentation Center around TrainingProgressFunction and PutAppend:

```
logFile = CreateTemporary[];
appendToLog = PutAppend[<|"Loss" -> #RoundLoss|>, logFile] &;
(*I have skipped the "Batch" -> #AbsoluteBatch output*)
trainingData = {#1, #2} -> {#1 + Sin[#1*#2]} & @@@ 
RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {50000, 2}];
NetTrain[
NetChain[{1000, Tanh, 1}, "Input" -> 2],trainingData, MaxTrainingRounds->10, 
TrainingProgressFunction -> appendToLog];
(*I am training for 10 rounds*)
```

Despite the fact that I am training for 10 rounds, the log file consists of 9 entries, the last round loss is omitted

```
logDataLength = Length[ReadList[logFile]]
9
```

Is there any alternative way to include also the last output? I can create a function appending the last output to the already existing list, but if I want to export for each and every round the weights and the biases of a large neural network (e.g. in total 15,000) this becomes quiet cumbersome.

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't tried this, but perhaps `TrainingProgressFunction -> {appendToLog, "Interval"->Quantity[1,"Rounds"]` or more likely `TrainingProgressFunction -> {appendToLog, "Interval"->Quantity[.999,"Rounds"]` would work?

Comment: `TrainingProgressFunction -> {appendToLog, "Interval" -> Quantity[1, "Rounds"]}` appears to work correctly.

Comment: @Carl, thanks a lot! However, I still get only 9 entries instead of 10 (11.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)). If I use "Interval"->Quantity[.999,"Rounds"] then the first entry, for the first iteration, is None.

Comment: I ended up having better luck with `Quantity[.99,"Rounds"]`, but that approach kind of sucks anyway. I'm on 11.3 with no issue for `Quantity[1,"Rounds"]`. Potentially you could set BatchSize and do `Quantity[batchsize-1,"Batches"]`?

Comment: Another way to do this (only available after training) is using the third argument to NetTrain. `nto = NetTrain[NetChain[{1000, Tanh, 1}, "Input" -> 2], trainingData, All, 
 MaxTrainingRounds -> 10]` and then `nto["RoundLossList"]`.

Comment: Is there any problem with either TrainingProgressFunction or PutAppend (in the context of NetTrain)?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. However, since it seems like you only need the loss after the network has been trained, you _could_ get it afterwards from the `NetTrainResultsObject` as my previous comment displays. Or you could do both, so that you can monitor the network's training using the log file _and_ have a full record at the end from the `NetTrainResultsObject`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Carl for your responses! As I am writing in my question, I want to retrieve a bit more complicated information from NetTrain (not the RoundLoss) which works fine with the TrainingProgressFunction and PutAppend approach only up to N-1 training rounds, where N is the total number of training rounds.

Comment: I understand. Unfortunately I can't replicate the issue with `TrainingProgressReporting` only running 9 times - it consistently runs 10 times for me with `"Interval" -> Quantity[1,"Rounds"]`. Are you on 11.3? Related: in 12.0, there will be more features for this type of reporting, so if nothing else this part of the codebase will have been touched :)

Comment: Thanks Carl. For "Interval" -> Quantity[1,"Rounds"], I am still getting 9 entries for 10 training rounds. I am on 11.2 so I might have to upgrade to 11.3.

Comment: async training will be added in 12.0, then u can define a logger. implement it now is meaningless.